# Swap two variables in Lolcode

Tags: lolcode

What command do I need to swap two variables's values in one line using Lolcode? I've tried looking at [Specification](https://github.com/justinmeza/lolcode-spec/blob/master/v1.2/lolcode-spec-v1.2.md), but failed to find any info about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i thnk thts right
**a,a R b,b R IT**